# Insert small icon (Emotion) in text message like Facebook chat message

Tags: javafx, icons, chat

I'm creating a Chat application with JavaFX in fron-end.
In text message, I want to combine text and icon (emotion) like this

[image]

(Sr, I don't have enough reputation to post image)

With JavaFx, how can I do this ???

Comment: When I research in Google, I see someone mention about TextFlow but I am developing my app in JDK 7.

Comment: Switch to JDK 8, because with JDK 7, you are missing many features of JavaFX ;)

Comment: Thank for suggestion ! If I don't have any solution, I will switch to JDK 8 :D